# Why I can't type ñ in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I use this character to type the name of employee in my program vb6, but I can't type it. When I type alt+164 the letter c is appearing instead of ñ. How can I type this one? Is it on my program or on my computer? But I can type ñ in my computer in other applications e.g word,notepad.

Comment: How? I tried the program in another computer, but I can type the letter ñ.

Comment: Check the computer regional settings: language for non-Unicode programs.

Comment: Where are you trying to type it? In the Code, form designer? Why are you hard coding names/data int he application itself?